# What are the flags for drawWindow?

Tags: canvas, firefox-addon

The MDN docs page says you can use flags with drawWindow:
[MDN DOC page on drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FCanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29)

But it doesnt list the flags anywhere. Does anyone know what the flags are?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags are actually listed on that page, in the [Gecko-specific constants section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Gecko-specific_constants), it is merely somewhat non-obvious. Currently, the possible flags are:

- DRAWWINDOW_DRAW_CARET (0x01)
- DRAWWINDOW_DO_NOT_FLUSH (0x02)
- DRAWWINDOW_DRAW_VIEW (0x04)
- DRAWWINDOW_USE_WIDGET_LAYERS (0x08)
- DRAWWINDOW_ASYNC_DECODE_IMAGES (0x10)

Comment: ah so easy it was right there haha thanks man! the reason i was looking for the flags is because when i do the drawWindow i notice quality is reduced on the canvas, but now i dont see a flag that maintains the hi quality, do you know how i can draw and maintain perfect pixel to pixel quality? edit: oh maybe its ```DRAWWINDOW_ASYNC_DECODE_IMAGES``` what do you think?